# read objects persisted but not yet flushed with doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm new to symfony2 and doctrine.
here is the problem as **I** see it.
i cannot use :

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('entity');
$my_object = $repository->findOneBy($index);
```

on an object that is persisted, BUT NOT FLUSHED YET !!
i think getRepository read from DB, so it will not find a not-flushed object.

my question: how to read those objects that are persisted (i think they are somewhere in a "doctrine session") to re-use them before i do flush my entire batch ?

every profile has 256 physical plumes.

every profile has 1 `plumeOptions` record assigned to it.

In `plumeOptions`, I have a cartridgeplume which is a FK for `PhysicalPlume`.

every plume is identified by `ID` (auto-generated) and an `INDEX` (user-generated).

rule: I say profile 1 has `physical_plume_index` number 3 (=index) connected to it.

now, I want to copy a profile with all its related data to another profile.

new profile is created. New 256 plumes are created and copied from older profile.

**i want to link the new profile to the new plume index 3.**

check here: http://pastebin.com/WFa8vkt1

Answer (score 22):

I think you might want to have a look at this function:

```
$entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions()
```

Gives you back a list of entity objects which are persisting yet.

Hmm, I didn't really read your question well, with the above you will retrieve a full list (as an array) but you cannot query it like with getRepository. I will try found something for u..

Comment: can i do a double flush() inside my action ??
i never tried it, but just a question.. maybe a dumb one ?!?
i flush the newly created plumes, and then i continue fetching the other plumeOptions and i can now link them to the newly created plumes.
how do yo find that idea...? (hopefully not so stupid !!)

Comment: As far as I know you can call flush() as many times you want. Offcourse best-practice is to do this as less as possible to preserve connection traffic. But if you need id's from your previous added entities then it's a good practice.

Comment: Is it possible to perform a find from persisted entities but not flushed ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you might look at the problem from the wrong angle. Doctrine is your persistance layer and database access layer. It is the responsibility of your domain model to provide access to objects once they are in memory. So the problem boils down to `how do you get a reference to an object without the persistance layer`?

Where do you create the object you need to get hold of later? Can the method/service that create the object return a reference to the controller so it can propagate it to the other place you need it? Can you dispatch an event that you listen to elsewhere in your application to get hold of the object?

In my opinion, Doctrine should be used at the startup of the application (as early as possible), to initialize the domain model, and at the shutdown of the application, to persist any changes to the domain model during the request. To use a repository to get hold of objects in the middle of a request is, in my opinion, probably a code smell and you should look at how the application flow can be refactored to remove that need.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree it's not the job of Doctrine to provide access. At least in Zend, Doctrine is used as the **Entity Manager** which to me sounds exactly like the place that should contain references to objects. After code has determined it wants to persist and entity, the persistence layer, Doctrine, should be the only one that (in general) needs to care about whether entities are written to DB yet or not. Though perhaps in Zend the EntityManager can provide some other way to access entities other than the Doctrine repositories, but if so, I don't know what that way is.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question :/

Answer (score 0):

Your is a business logic problem effectively.

Querying down the Database a findby Query on Object that are not flushed yet, means heaving much more the DB layer querying object that you have already in your function scope.

Also Keep in mind a findOneBy will retrieve also other object previously saved with same features.

If you need to find only among those new created objects, you should make f.e. them in a Session Array Variable, and iterate them with the foreach.

If you need a mix of already saved items + some new items, you should threate the 2 parts separately, one with a foreach , other one with the repository query!