# Where to put pre-flush entity state data in Zend where EntityRepository can access it?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have an `Person` that is many-to-one with a `Family`. The system takes in many rows of data with multiple persons at the same time, which may or may not belong to the same families. I don't have the information about families beforehand.

When I process a `Person` to enter into the system, I check whether I need to add its `Family` to the database first. I naturally ask about that from `FamilyRepository`, but even if I've already created and persisted the same `Family`, the `FamilyRepository` still doesn't know about this, since it's written to database only at `flush()`.

The solution would be to temporarily add a reference to *somewhere* during the `PrePersist` of the newly created `Family`, and make the `FamilyRepository` check from that place as well as from the database.

But **where should this temporary persisted-but-not-yet-flushed entity reference go, so that I can access it from the entity's repository**?

Alternative solutions I don't like:

- The code that does the adding (`PersonService->insertPersons()`) could of course keep track of the persisted entities, but this seems like a non-optimal solution since it is not a general solution and that code would have to be put each place that adds data.
- I could just flush after each addition, but I'd prefer not to flush until all the data has been processed.
- I [could](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7879164/115807) also loop through `$entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions()`, and find entries from there, but that seems rather like a hack than an actual solution.

Comment: You might take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877987/read-objects-persisted-but-not-yet-flushed-with-doctrine

Comment: @netiul Thanks for the related link. I don't think the answers there are solutions to my question, though. I guess I could loop through `getScheduledEntityInsertions()` but that seems more of a hack as well - I edited the question to include this. The answer by PatrikAkerstrand makes sense, but it would require a rather large refactoring to use a custom reference objects for all entities (and besides, isn't that excatly what the entity manager should do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you can handle this by manually handling your transactions (assuming you're using the ORM, anyway.  Not sure about transaction support in ODM).

By wrapping your whole import in a transaction, you can make incremental flushes so that SELECTs issued by the repository will return the data, but you can still rollback the entire thing if something goes wrong:

```
<?php

$em->beginTransaction();
$familyRepository = $em->getRepository('Family');

foreach($personData as $p){
    $lastname = $p['lastname'];

    $person = new Person();
    $person->setLastname($lastname);

    $family = $familyRepository->findOneByLastname($lastname);

    if (! $family){
        $family = new Family();
        $family->setLastname($lastname);
        $em->persist($family);
    }

    $person->setFamily($family);
    $em->persist($person);
    $em->flush();
}
$em->commit();
```

Comment: Hmm, you are right that transaction rollback does achieve the same result as not flushing. I guess the problem could be that I am confused about the whole flush concept - I've sort of felt it is expected to be used like transactions, sort of "Ok, I'm done" signal for the persistence layer. But I guess it could be that it's just meant to be more ephemeral, leaving the "Ok, I'm done" up to transactions.

Comment: It really depends on your use case.  I find that as time has gone on, I tend to handle transaction demarcation myself.   It's also very handy for testing, as you can s/commit()/rollback/ while developing and watch your mysql query log to see what doctrine is doing under the hood.  When manually handling transactions, flush() simply sends the queries to the database, but since START TRANSACTION has happened, they aren't committed until you explicitly call commit().

Comment: Yes, it's very useful for debugging weird doctrine behaviour. Still I can't shake the feeling that it's a bit hacky and wrong solution. The point of a db persistence layer is that the code shouldn't in theory care when entites are in memory, when they are in db, or they are in a transaction (unless it's a critical atomic operation of course). But maybe that's rather just my personal problem. :)

Comment: Doctrine depends on "identity" which it gets from lower layers (primary keys).  That's rational.  The only source of truth for identity is the underlying data store.  I suppose in a perfect world, as soon as you persist() some entity, the EM would know about it ... but that's impossible given the 98% use case of people using mysql with AUTO_INCREMENT.  In the end, if you're doing more than simple CRUD on simple entities, my experience says it's worth your time to handle transactions explicitly.  If you don't, you're asking for magic.

Comment: Impossible, perhaps in general. But not for custom repository query functions. If my abstract entity (that all entities inherit from) has a pre-persist function that stores the ID and the object in some location, and my abstract object repository has a custom "give entity with id" function (the most typical case) that I write to also check the location for non-flushed objects, that provides the functionality. Sure, you can't do general findBy-queries, but the typical case is covered. Which is pretty much what I was asking in my question, albeit my question was simplified for focus.

Comment: Well, sure.  If you assign an ID in your application code, you can do all sorts of things.  The hard part, in the general case, is persisting those entities to some durable store.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point, I can't use the default id. Sorry, completely missed that though it's indeed rather obvious. In my case I was using an external uid for the entities anyway, so didn't matter. Thanks for the discussion!